# python modules subfolders not available after import

Tags: python, module, package

I have coded a few python scrips and now I would like to pack them in a single module. The idea is to create a few folders to organize them better.

The structure is like this

```
mylib
    __init__.py
    area1
        __init__.py
        group11.py
    area2
        __init__.py
        group12.py
```

The `__init__.py` files contain only the `__all__` variable. The top level one is `__all__ = ["area1", "area2"]`, the others are like this `__all__ = ["group11"]` Assume that `group11.py` contains the function `def test():` that I want to invoke.

Once I install my package I have the following results

```
import mylib # --> ok
mylib.area1.group11.test() # --> module 'mylib' has no attribute 'area1'

import mylib.area1.group # --> ok
mylib.area1.group11.test() # --> ok

from mylib.area1 import group11 # --> ok
group11.test() # --> ok
```

Why the first solution doesn't work? Should I add something in the `__all__` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely normal.
You are not defining the symbol `area1` in your `mylib` package, hence the error.

**Option 1**

One solution would be exporting all symbols from you subpackage as following:

```py
from . import area1
```

**Option 2**

Another way too make it work you should at least import that symbol in your package, i.e.

```py
# mylib/area1/group11.py

def test():
   print 'hello'
```

```py
# mylib/__init__.py

from area1.group11 import test
```

```py
import mylib
mylib.test() # OK

import mylib.area1.group11
mylib.area1.group11.test() # OK
```

However, since your symbol `test` is defined in `mylib.area1.group11` you won't be able by *only* importing `mylib` to access the sub-packages and modules therein.

What I am trying to say is that, when you do `import mylib` you import the symbols defined in `mylib/__init__.py`, not sub-packages, nor the sub-modules. You have to import them as well.

**Warning**: You will have to do the same in `mylib/area1/__init__.py` and `mylib/area2/__init__.py` if you want to "export"/define symbols from `mylib/area1/group11.py`

For more details:

- [How Python modules are resolved](https://gist.github.com/twolfson/7636887)
- [The Definitive Guide to Python import Statements](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html)

Comment: when I try to add `import area1` in `mylib/__init__.py` file, I get the error "unable to import area1". The same applies for `import group11` in `mylib/area1/__init__.py` file

Comment: Thanks for your effort! At a certain point you said in a comment to add something like `from . import area1`. I think that did the trick exactly as I wanted, while the new solution `from area1.group11 import test` makes something slightly different. Can you change it back to `from . import area1`? It makes sense that I approve it as the correct solution

Comment: Ok, I re-edited the message in order to have both answers :-)